AWS lambda support Java AWT
I am trying to run below example on AWS lambda, which is drawing a box around the face: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/images-displaying-bounding-boxes.html
getting below error:

Tried to set headless as false, which didn't work: System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");
As per error DISPLAY is not set so we tried to set DISPLAY=:1.0 in AWS Lambda > Configuration > Environment Variables but got below error:

Tried to load library by setting property like below, but didn't work:
System.setProperty("java.library.path", "/var/lang/lib/");
System.loadLibrary("libawt_xawt.so");
Need help for necessary configuration to run below example in AWS lambda:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/images-displaying-bounding-boxes.html
Also, how can resolve java.awt.HeadlessException: No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.

Lambda is a headless environment - it's not clear why you set java.awt.headless to false.  And the error you're getting isn't about libawt_xawt.so but rather libXext.so.6.  A headless environment is unlikely to have this library.

Hi @stdunbar had discussion with AWS team and they suggested:
"Java AWT can be used in headless mode in lambda environments without display in general but only for components that support headless mode. While heavyweight AWT components like Frame do not support this, lightweight components such as Canvas, Panel etc. can be useful"
To sum it up for our context, JFrame cannot be used in lambda(even in headless mode) as it needs a display.  I replaced JFrame changes with canvas and its working. Thanks for your help
